# return datat as json in razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using asp core razor pages ,
and i'm trying to return data as json by controller

this is working fine for me :

```
return Json(new { data = _db.Clients.FromSqlRaw("select * from Clients where nom_createur != 'X'").ToList() });
```

But this

```
 return Json(new { data = _db.Clients.FromSqlRaw("select  nom_createur,COUNT(Id_Client) as 'counte'  from clients where Nom_Createur != 'X' group by nom_createur").ToList() });
```

given this error :

```
The required column 'Id_Client' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation
```

ps: i really need to use **FromSqlRaw**

Comment: try deleting the alias "as 'counte'". That may be what's breaking it. Also, try adding COUNT(Id_Client)  in your group by.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Check the Name of  `Id_Client` in `clients` table designer.

Comment: @MichaelWang if u asking the query is working just fine in sql server